# How do you control what fields Spring Roo uses in list.jspx?

Tags: model-view-controller, spring

I'm using Spring Roo 1.1.2 and trying to have meaningful list pages but that's more difficult than I would expect.

For instance, I want a list of People objects; listed in Last Name, First Name order and then the utilbox icons.

I took the default list.jspx and updated it to:

```
<page:list id="id_snipped_Person" items="${persons}" z="user-managed">
    <table:table data="${athletes}" id="id_snipped_Person" path="/persons" z="user-managed">
        <table:column id="id_snipped_Person_lastName" property="lastName" z="user-managed" maxLength="50"/>
        <table:column id="id_snipped_Person_firstName" property="firstName" z="user-managed" maxLength="20" />
    </table:table>
```

I over-wrote every "z" attribute that I could find to "user-managed" yet the next time I start Roo, I'm presented with:

```
[FelixDispatchQueue] Updated SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/WEB-INF/views/persons/list.jspx
```

Where my lastName and firstName fields are still there, they are now trailed by 6-8 other fields from the Person object.

How do I tell Roo to back off on this table element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can "hide" unwanted columns by setting render="false" property,

for example

```
<page:list id="id_snipped_Person" items="${persons}" z="user-managed">
    <table:table data="${athletes}" id="id_snipped_Person" path="/persons" z="user-managed">
        <table:column  render="false"  id="id_snipped_Person_lastName" property="lastName" z="user-managed" maxLength="50"/>
        <table:column id="id_snipped_Person_firstName" property="firstName" z="user-managed" maxLength="20" />
    </table:table>
```

will not render last name column

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was actually trying to find a way that wouldn't clutter the .jsp with X number of "<table:column .. .render="false" /> lines for those situations when I want to compeletely rewrite the jsp from scratch.  Any ideas?

Comment: maybe on springsource forums someone could help, but I think that Roo needs to be informed that those columns should not be generated, so I'm not sure if it's even possible

Comment: Is there a way to generate the pages with only the foreign key ids rather then the all the columns . something like as in SQL Client.